# Send multicast message to GCM from app server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

Can i send a multicast message to gcm and gcm does not send the message to all devices simultaneously. Rather it sends the message to all devices one by one after 5 seconds etc. I mean, is it possible to program gcm actions to make it send messages after particular time.